Are weakly monotonic preference and strictly monotomic preference the same?
Recently I am reviewing preference theory and I found that I am confused about the difference between weakly monotonic preference and strictly monotonic preference.
Now, let us suppose $X$ is the consumption set. If my understanding is correct, then:

Preference is said to be weakly monotonic if for $x,y \in X$, $y \gg x$ implies $y \succ x$.

Preference is said to be strictly monotonic if for $x,y \in X$, $y \geq x$ implies $y \succeq x$, and $y \gg x$ implies $y \succ x$.


So it seems that weakly monotonic preference says nothing when $y \geq x$ but not $y \gg x$ (for example, $y=(1,1,2)$ and $x=(1,1,1)$)? Maybe we can have $y \prec x$ if the preference is weakly monotonic?

Weak monotonicity, according to your definition, is just being agnostic about cases where $x\ge y$. It is "weak" because it imposes one fewer condition relative to the "strict" version. Also note that different authors (e.g. Kreps (2013)) define monotonicity differently (see related question).

For continuous preferences, these are equivalent. Usually, "strictly monotone" refers to the stronger condition that $y\geq x$ and $y\neq x$ implies $y\succ x$.

Thank all of you very much. The info you provided is really helpful.

@MichaelGreinecker Hi, in the question https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/55185/conflicting-definitions-of-weak-monotnocity-preferences you mentioned that if $\succeq$ is locally nonsatiated, then M1 implies M2. However I failed to prove it, could you explain how can we approach this conclusion?

@ShujunTan Let $x\succ y$. There is a neighborhood of $y$ such that for every point $z$ in the neighborhood, $x\gg z$. The neighborhood must also contain a point $z$ such that $z\succ y$ by local nonsatiation. Then, $x\geq z\succ y$. By M1, $x\succeq z\succ y$. Hence, $x\succ y$.

@MichaelGreinecker. Thanks. However I am struggling to understand why if $x \succ y$, then there is a neighborhood of $y$ such that for every point $z$ in the neighborhood, $x \gg z$.
If only M1 is given, then M1 keeps silent on what relation between $x$ and $y$ must make $x \succ y$. So, for example, if $x=(1,2)$ and $y=(2,1)$, then it is possible that we have $x \succ y$ under M1. However, any neighborhood of $y$ has at least one point $z$ such that $x \not\gg z$.

@ShujunTan Sorry, that's a typo. The first $x\succ y$ should be $x\gg y$.

You're on the right track in understanding the difference between weakly monotonic and strictly monotonic preferences.
1. Weakly Monotonic Preferences:
Preferences are weakly monotonic if for any two consumption bundles x and y, if y strictly greater than x (meaning that every element in y is strictly greater than the corresponding element in x), then y > x (you strictly prefer y over x).
What it doesn't guarantee:
Weakly monotonic preferences do not require a clear preference between two bundles if one is only greater than or equal to the other, but not strictly greater (e.g., y >= x, such as y = (1,1,2) and x = (1,1,1)).
In these cases, the preference might not be clear, and it's possible under weakly monotonic
preferences that you might actually prefer x over y (i.e., y <= x), or be indifferent. Weak monotonicity doesn't tell us anything about this scenario.
2. Strictly Monotonic Preferences:
Preferences are strictly monotonic if: - For y >= x, you at least weakly prefer y over x (i.e., y <= x). This means if y is greater than or equal to x in all dimensions,you cannot prefer x over y, though you might be indifferent. - For y strictly greater than x, you strictly prefer y over x (i.e., y > x).
Key Difference:
Weakly monotonic: Only ensures strict preference if y strictly greater than x. It is silent on what happens when y >= x but not y strictly greater than x, so it's possible to have y <= x in this case.
Strictly monotonic: Always ensures that y >= x means you at least weakly prefer y, and if y strictly greater than x, you strictly prefer y over x.
In your example, if preferences are weakly monotonic, it's possible for y = (1,1,2) to be strictly worse than x = (1,1,1), since weak monotonicity doesn't provide guidance when y >= x but not y strictly greater than x. However, in the case of strictly monotonic preferences,y = (1,1,2) would be at least weakly preferred to x = (1,1,1).
